# Using PDO to insert data into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I'm trying to use PDO to insert data into my database but I'm getting the error "0 results". I already used PDO to select data from my database but this is the first time I use it to insert data so any help with the below code would be appreciated!

**My form:**

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="blog post" action="insert.php" method="post">

<label for "id">Id: </label>
<input type="text" name="id">
<br>    
<label for "title">Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="title">
<br>    
<label for "year">Year: </label>
<input type="text" name="year">
<br>    
<label for "text">Text: </label>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="text"></textarea>
<br>    
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**My insert.php code:**

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbexample', 'userexample', 'paswexample', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8;SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'"));

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tableexample` (id, title, year, text)
                                        VALUES (:id, :title, :year, :text)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $title);
$stmt->bindParam(":year", $year);
$stmt->bindParam(":text", $text);

$form = $_POST;
$id = $form[ 'id' ];                    
$title= $form[ 'title' ];                   
$year= $form[ 'year' ];                 
$text= $form[ 'text' ];                 


$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':title'=>$title, ':year'=>$year, ':text'=>$text));

if($result) {
    echo "Your text has been posted";

    }// end if
else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':title'=>$title, ':year'=>$year, ':text'=>$text));
```

with this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

---

or...use only:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':title'=>$title, ':year'=>$year, ':text'=>$text));
```

and remove all of `$stmt->bindParam`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using the first option now and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
  try{
        $stmt = null;               
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mst_finish (id, title, year, text) VALUES (:title, ':year', :text)");       
        $data = array(              
            ':title' => ucwords($_REQUEST['title']),
            ':year' => strtoupper($_REQUEST['year']),
            ':text' => $_REQUEST['text']);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        $_SESSION['_msg'] = "Finish succesfully saved..!";
     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {      
        $str= filter_var($e->getMessage(), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);         
        $_SESSION['_msg_err'] = $str;           
     }
```